# How to get all the friends from facebook using hull?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using hull in my ruby on rails application to connect social media sites. From facebook I want to get all the friends details (like name, photo, and email). I used the following code which was given in the hull.io document. But it is not working. Can anyone suggest me how to get those details?

My code:

```
 Hull.api({provider:  'facebook',  path:  'me/friends'})
 .then(function  (friends)  {
  console.log(friends);
 },  function  ()  {
  console.log("The request has failed");
 });
```

The above code is returning only total sum of friends.

Comment: You can only get friends that are using the app. Not all friends. It is not possible

Comment: How to get those friends whom r using app?

Comment: You call /me/friends it will return all friends that have granted user_friends to the app if you have it

Comment: IS there any possible way to get all my friends?

Comment: not for what you want to do, no

Answer (score 1):

- You can only get friends who authorized your App too, for privacy reasons
- You can´t get the email of any friend, only the email of the authorized user by using the "email" permission in the login process

In your case, there is no way to get all friends, but if you want to invite friends you can use [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/invitable_friends) and if you want to tag friends you can use [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/taggable_friends). But remember, those are for inviting and tagging only, and you should read the articles in the Facebook docs for the rules for using them.